# How to fix the memory limit exceeded problem

Tags: java

This is a Leetcode problem 374. Guess Number Higher or Lower. The
descriptions are as follows:

We are playing the Guess Game. The game is as follows: I pick a number from 1 to n. You have to guess which number I picked. Every time you guess wrong, I will tell you whether the number I picked is higher or lower than your guess. You call a pre-defined API int guess(int num), which returns three possible results:

- -1: Your guess is higher than the number I picked (i.e. num > pick).
- 1: Your guess is lower than the number I picked (i.e. num < pick).
- 0: your guess is equal to the number I picked (i.e. num == pick). Return the number that I picked.

My code is shown below and Leetcode gave me the "memory limit exceeded" error when submitting. How do I fix it? Thanks!

```
/** 
 * Forward declaration of guess API.
 * @param  num   your guess
 * @return       -1 if num is higher than the picked number
 *                1 if num is lower than the picked number
 *               otherwise return 0
 * int guess(int num);
 */

public class Solution extends GuessGame {
    public int guessNumber(int n) {
        int[] nums = new int[n];
        for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
            nums[i] = i+1;
        }    
        return search(nums,1,n,(int) ((1+n)/2));  
    }
    
    
    public int search(int[] nums, int L, int R, int myguess) { //L,R are values not index
        if (L < R) {
            if (guess(myguess) == 0) {
                return myguess;
            }
            else if (guess(myguess) < 0) { //myguess > pick
                return search(nums,L,myguess-1,(int) ((L+myguess-1)/2));
            }
            else {
                return search(nums,myguess+1,R,(int) ((R+myguess+1)/2));
            }
        }
        else {
            return (L+R)/2;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is [infinite recursion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/finite-and-infinite-recursion-with-examples/).  You must ensure that "guess(myguess) == 0" at some point before you run out of stack space!

Comment: Why is your post an entire quote? Please don't blindly copy-paste, read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) and make sure to use proper [markdown](/markdown).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Sorry, stackoverflow kept saying that I have code in the description section so making them quote was a quick fix to be able to post.

Comment: It is definitely endless recursion. in `search`. No need to cast to int, `/``  is integer division, 3/2 == 1.

Comment: @amy555_t why would you need a quick fix instead of a proper fix? Your post is going to live on SO for years to come, putting in the time up front to make sure it's [a good question](/help/how-to-ask) is _highly_ recommended if you don't want to run the risk of it getting closed. As for code: you have `<br>` codes in your post, don't write html, don't blindly copy-paste from an email or another forum: just take that little bit of time to write normal text before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, got it fixed.

```
public class Solution extends GuessGame {
    public int guessNumber(int n) {
        return search(1,n,((1+n)/2));  
    }
    
    
    public int search(int L, int R, int myguess) { //L,R are values not index
        while (L <= R) {
            myguess = L + (R-L)/2;
            if (guess(myguess) == 0) {
                return myguess;
            }
            else if (guess(myguess) < 0) { //myguess > pick
                R = myguess - 1;
            }
            else {
                L = myguess + 1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).